# How to end the Completion Block in Next ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks, nsnotificationcenter

I am having the below block in ViewController A

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissAnimated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"adjustNavBar"
                                                            object:self];
    }];
});
```

After the execution of 'dismissAnimated' block method the NSNotificationCenter is getting called and the Observer in ViewController B is executing the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                            selector:@selector(adjustNavBar)
                            name:@"adjustNavBar"
                            object:nil];
}

-(void)adjustNavBar {
    [self checkForPartialScroll];
}
```

after execution of the above code, it is ending in ViewController A.

But i want to end the process in ViewController B. How to do this, i am newly trying this callback functions.

using Delegates or Callbacks, can i achieve what i am trying ?

Comment: you want to remove observer in homeviewcontroller ?

Comment: No. After executing one method in homeviewcontroller, it is coming back to end the process in FirstViewController. I want to end the execution in homeviewcontroller.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, but I am sure there is a simpler way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do.  What do you mean it ends in FirstViewController?

Comment: i edited my question @Paulw11 Changed First and Home ViewController to A and B ViewControllers.

Comment: @R.Mohan what do you mean "end the process in ViewController B"? what is the problem? Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: i got struck at communicating between classes, when using completion blocks. I used NSNotificationCenter to update some ui in someother class from the current class. Tried the same but unable to achieve it, that is my issue.

Comment: Actually 'dismissAnimated' method will dismiss the ViewController A and move to ViewController B. Inbetween this i am trying to change a UIView's Y-axis which is in ViewController B.

Comment: Don't do this man. Notifications can really cause a headache. I highly supremely suggest you to learn about protocol & delegates. It's the best thing ever.

Comment: This is the first time i am facing trouble with NSNotificationCenter, I know about protocol & delegates, will try it now. Thank you for this suggestion @GeneCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try post `notification` before `dismissviewcontroller`:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"adjustNavBar" object:self];  

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissAnimated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
});
```

if not work , try run `checkForPartialScroll` in mainthread

Comment: Added main queue fpr 'checkForPartialScroll' method , and it does the magic @Nguyen Hoan. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

write that code above your code ,
HomeVC name of your next VC &
@"HomeVC" identifier of your next VC

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
  HomeVC *homeVC = (HomeVC *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
    }
```

Comment: Actually the 'dismissAnimated' method will push the HomeVC, so your suggestion won't work i guess.